# Condition for A,B s.t $x_{n+1}=\frac{112233+Ax_n^2}{Bx_n}$ converges

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

> Given the following fixed point iteration $x_{n+1}=\frac{112233+Ax_n^2}{Bx_n}$ find values for A,B s.t the iteration converges to $\alpha$ (a root) with maximal order of convergence. Find the order.

After simplifying it we get that $G(x)=\frac {112233}{Bx}+\frac A Bx$. We want to find $K>0$ bounds the derivative. $G\prime(x)=-\frac{112233}{Bx^2}+\frac A B$ but I can't bound it since in [0,1] (No interval was mentioned so maybe the writer meant convergence on $(-\infty,\infty)$) the derivative is not bounded. What conditions can I require on A,B s.t the iteration converges?

Comment: Why do we want to bound the derivative? If it was $x_{n + 1} = K · x_n$ then we would have $G(x) = Kx$, $G'(x) = K$ which is bounded. Yet for $K > 1$, $x_0 ≠ 0$, the sequence does not converge. In your example, if $A/B > 1$, $B > 0$ and some $x_n > 0$ then it goes to ∞.

Comment: Fixed point theorem claims that if $G,G\prime$ are continuous, and G is surjective function on $[a,b]$, if $|G\prime(x)|\le K<1, \forall x\in [a,b]$, then the iteration converges to a fixed point of G. That's why I require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:the max order means the highest derivative that is different from 0.

Comment: I know it's first derivative. my problem is the values of A,B...